# Распаковка архива с помощью класса ZipArchive

Tags: php, zip

У меня есть форма, которая принимает zip-файл и распаковывает его в папку через метод `extractTo` класса `ZipArchive`. Можно ли как-то переименовывать в процессе извлечения? А то в эту папку ещё дозаливать файлы можно, но если вдруг одинаковые названия, то заменится. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: разархивировать в новую папку, а после разархивации уже "мержить" эти 2 папки.